# Distinction entre les interjections "hein", "hum", "euh" et similaires

Tags: interjections

En cherchant comment traduire des interjections du genre "hein" et "huh" à partir de l'anglais, je me suis rendu compte qu'il y a apparemment des différences entre l'utilisation de ces mêmes interjections en français.

Par exemple, le "hein" est mentionné dans quelques dictionnaires en ligne (p. ex. [Larousse](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/huh/), [blabla](http://www.babla.fr/anglais-francais/huh)) comme étant une traduction de "huh". Cependant, parfois une meilleure traduction semblerait être "hum". Y a-t-il une correspondance directe entre "hein" et "huh"?

Entre "hein", "hum", "euh", et similaires, leur utilisation ne me semble pas tout à fait hasardeuse, mais je ne vois pas clairement quand les utiliser.

Je me demande s'il y a des règles plus précises sur l'utilisation de ces interjections ; les dictionnaires donnent des exemples, mais pas une description générale de leur utilisation, ce qui pourrait faciliter la compréhension.

Comment: Peux-tu donner une source pour « hein » en anglais ? Le [Wiktionnaire](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hein) ne connait pas et je n'arrive même pas à imaginer comment le prononcer. Je ne l'ai jamais rencontré et ne voit donc pas comment il peut être traduit en français.

Comment: En effet, je crois m'être trompé, je ne retrouve plus de référence à "hein" en anglais, sauf en tant qu'argot Québécois... j'ai modifié la question pour en tenir compte.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On les utilise souvent dans ce genre de contexte :

> *hein* ? qu'est-ce que tu dis ?

... je suis interpellé, je n'ai pas compris ; *hein* invite à faire répéter ce qui vient d'être dit.

> *hum*, la question est embarrassante.

... c'est plutôt une interjection personnelle, *hum*, voyons voir ce que je vais bien pouvoir faire.

> *euh*... j'sais  pas moi.

... *euh* est une exclamation d'ignorance ou d'attente : pour eux qui disent *euh* dans le silence qui dure pendant qu'ils cherchent dans leur tête la phrase à formuler. Expression familière, exclamation à éviter preuve de faiblesse du discours, ou d'ignorance du sujet évoqué.

N'étant pas anglophone, je ne connais pas les expressions anglaises correspondantes.

Answer (score 5):

La [réponse de cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13940/7224) donne les exemples les plus courants d'utilisation des interjections que tu as citées.

La traduction est rarement unique. Comme en français, elle dépend du contexte, du style dont un personnage ou une personne s'exprime et de ses interlocuteurs (en français, on n'hésitera pas à employer « hein ? » avec des proches, mais on essaiera généralement d'utiliser un « quoi ? » moins familier lorsque l'on échange avec un supérieur).

### Hein ?

La [traduction](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/hein) dépend du contexte.

Le plus courant est l'**incompréhension**, l'invitation à répéter ou expliquer. « *What* » est le premier équivalent anglais qui me vient en tête, mais WordReference suggère aussi « *eh* », qui s'utilise de la même manière mais est plus familier.

« *Huh?* » est une traduction d'incompréhension, qui se traduit également par « Hein ? ».

> *Hein* ? Qu'est-ce que tu dis ?
>
> *What*? What are you saying?
>
> *Eh*? Were you speaking to me?

On utilise aussi parfois « hein ? » en fin de phrase pour **inviter à la confirmation**. Ceci correspond à la traditionnelle forme anglaise « *isn't it?* » et ses dérivés. Pour des formes avec une familiarité croissante, on a les alternatives « *no?* » et « *heh?* » (ce dernier véhicule en plus une certaine satisfaction de soi). Cette forme me paraît moins usitée en français, je pense qu'on se tourne plus facilement vers un simple « non ? » ou « tu ne trouves pas ? »

> Je suis trop génial, *hein ?*
>
> I genius, *aren't I?*

### Hum

« Hum » est une onomatopée. Elle peut être utilisée pour exprimer une **gêne**, une hésitation. L'équivalent le plus proche me semble « *er* ».

> *Hum*, c'est gênant...
>
> *Er*, this is awkward...

On peut également le trouver sous forme exclamative, plus affirmée, traduisant un son pouvant s'apparenter à une toux forcée, pour **signaler sa présence à un interlocuteur** qui ne nous a pas remarqué ou nous fait patienter.

Les [traductions](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/hum) courantes dans ce cas sont « *Hem!* » ou plus couramment « *Ahem!* »

### Euh

Deux formes ici. « Euh » exprime souvent une **incompréhension** et est équivalent à « *er* » (comme avec « hum », on traduit une *hésitation*).

On peut trouver « euh » dans une forme plus affirmative. Cette interjection se traduit alors par « uh ».

> *Euh*, je ne sais pas.
>
> *Uh*, I don't know.

En anglais, il est également d'utiliser « *well* » pour traduire « euh ». La signification est dans ce cas la volonté de marquer une réflexion, voire même de se donner un peu de temps. Un équivalent possible en français est « Eh bien ».

> *Euh/Eh bien*, laissez-moi réfléchir.
>
> *Well*, let me see.

### Anglais : huh

« *Huh* » peut aussi être utilisé pour exprimer un mépris. Il est alors écrit seul, suivi d'un point d'exclamation. À l'oral, il est prononcé de façon très courte. WordReference [propose « bof »](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/huh) mais phonétiquement, c'est quelque chose que je traduirais personnellement par un « Hm ! ». C'est le ton utilisé qui véhicule tout le mépris que contient cette expression.

Comment: Le "hein" en anglais c'était ma faute, en effet je ne le retrouve pas ; j'ai dû confondre les mentions en différentes langues.

Comment: Pas de problème, je préférais couvrir aussi largement que possible. Je vais retirer ce point de ma réponse.

Comment: En complément :  En anglais on utilise souvent  "well" pour "euh".

Comment: Je mets à jour. Merci du rappel.